# How to attach uncaught exception handler/completion to CompletableFuture chain

Tags: java-8, completable-future, uncaughtexceptionhandler

**The use-case**:

- an exception occurs during [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) chain
- **none** of [exceptionally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#exceptionally-java.util.function.Function-), [whenComplete](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenComplete-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) or [handle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#handle-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method is attached to that CompletableFuture chain

**The result**:
The exception is never caught and there's no tracking/log of it. Which in case of Async systems is 1) undesirable and 2) an indicator for hard and hidden problems (such as NPE, Runtime Exc, etc.) to spot.

**The question**:
Is it feasible to implement *CompletableFuture.UncaughtExceptionHandler* mechanism by analogy / in a similar manner with java.lang.[Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html)? The idea is to provide [default] uncaught exception handler/completion to be called if the CompletableFuture chain does not have java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.UniExceptionally Completion attached.

Comment: Where do you want to install that handler?

Comment: @Holger CompletableFuture.set[Default]UncaughtExceptionCompletion by analogy with Thread.set[Default]UncaughtExceptionHandler will be the ultimate solution. Still I'm open for any custom solution that will solve my use-case: prevent CompletableFuture chain from unhandled exception.

Comment: Are you proposing a change of the API? Then, it’s way too narrowly focussed on a particular use case. `CompletableFuture`s are not required to form simple chains; they may have arbitrarily complex dependency graphs. Further, you never know whether someone will add a dependent action that handles exception at some arbitrary later time. Or just call `join()` and handle the exception.

Comment: @Holger: A custom solution proposed that covers the use-case is good enough. Any idea is appreciated. I just need a default exception completion at the end of the CF chain.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: no.

However, someone posted an ugly hack to get similar behavior in another thread:
[How to handle uncaught exceptions from CompletableFuture.runAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218333/how-to-handle-uncaught-exceptions-from-completablefuture-runasync#)

I for one escape this problem by using ReactiveX (http://reactivex.io), but that choice might be beyond your control. In that case, you could consider creating a wrapped class for CompletableFuture that always registers an exception handler behind the scenes, so you don't have to explicitely call exceptionally(..) any more. But again, this is just a work-around.